# Print list items separated by any character instead of comma (Python)

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to divide particular **length** into **sections** and print **section** division_result times in row. The rest is divided by 2 and both placed at the beginning and the end of the list.
For now I have this:

```
section = 180
length_to_divide: int = 2150
interject = ' X '

division_result = length_to_divide / section
sides = (length_to_divide % section) / 2
whole = str(section).split() * int(division_result)
print(sides, whole, sides)
```

with the output

```
85.0 ['180', '180', '180', '180', '180', '180', '180', '180', '180', '180', '180'] 85.0
```

Is there any way to print list items in row, but instead comma split them by **interject = ' X '** in my case, I'd like to have an output like:

```
85.0 X 180 X 180 X 180 X 180 X 180 X 180 X 180 X 180 X 180 X 180 X 180 X 85.0
```

Comment: [str.join(iterable)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) would seem to fit the bill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option:

```
section = 180
length_to_divide: int = 2150
sides = str((length_to_divide % section) / 2)
whole = str(section).split() * int(length_to_divide / section)
s = ' X '.join([sides, *whole, sides])
print(s)
```

Answer (score 2):

The function `join` of string is your real answer

```
m_list = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
print('x'.join(m_list))
```

output:

```
1x2x3x4
```

in order to append more data you can append it at first to the list like so:

```
m_list = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
extra_num = 34
print('x'.join([str(extra_num)]+m_list))
```

output:

```
34x1x2x3x4
```

Comment: thanks Yossi, I'll try that solution.
One more question about numbers outside of the list.

Comment: Yossi thank you for the help. Everything works as it should be!!!

Answer (score 2):

This should solve it. I'm assuming whole is a list always.

```
section = 180
length_to_divide: int = 2150
interject = ' X '

division_result = length_to_divide / section
sides = (length_to_divide % section) / 2
whole = str(section).split() * int(division_result)
print(sides, *whole, sides, sep=' X ')
```

Gives Output:

> `85.0 X 180 X 180 X 180 X 180 X 180 X 180 X 180 X 180 X 180 X 180 X 180 X 85.0`

Answer (score 0):

```
section = 180
length_to_divide: int = 2150
interject = ' X '

division_result = length_to_divide / section
sides = (length_to_divide % section) / 2
whole = str(section).split() * int(division_result)
string = ' X '.join([str(x) for x in [sides] + whole + [sides]])
print(string)
```

Comment: Thanks @Alexandra, that solve all my questions, works perfect!